Enterprise Data Visualisation Tools Suggestions
I'm looking a very specific data visualisation tool for my use case;
The specific solution needs to be able to do the following ;

Fetch data from multiple sources, including REST API, so not just JS script embeds.
Be able to visualise that data in various ways, such customer journey, behavioural flow etc.

Is anyone aware of a tool that exists like this?

If you want decent flexibility Tableau, Grafana, or Power BI (especially good if you already have Microsoft 365 in your enterprise since it may be part of the package), or several others should all be capable of doing what you need here.
If you want more flexibility and can delve into the code yourself, something like d3.js or Highcharts (or many others) may give you more options for a lower cost of entry.
Caveat: I am basing this on experience that is a couple of years old, there may be newer tools that are even better, but these have been some pretty industry standard ones.
